# Checking that none of the html inputs should visually interfere with each other selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium, webdriver

Is there any way to checking if html `inputs` interfere each other visually selenium python?
For example below image has overlapping elements:

[image]

And second below image has no ovarlapping elements:

[image]

I want to check this in some different web page sizes like `800*600` and `1024*768`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get get `location` and `size` properties of each relevant element and calculate if there are interferences or not.
Like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

e = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//someXpath")

location = e.location
size = e.size
w, h = size['width'], size['height']

print(location)
print(size)
print(w, h)
```

The output here will be something like this:

```
{'y': 202, 'x': 165}
{'width': 77, 'height': 22}
77 22
```

Comment: Thanks. can "e"  be an array of all elements too?

Comment: No. You can get an attribute of any single web element while array of web elements does not have such properties. It is just a container. It may contain any object types.

Comment: How can i dynamically  check all "input"s of  any web pages?
e = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input") can not be an array

Comment: You can get all the elements to the list `inputs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input")` and then iterate over all the elements in the list and get each element location and size.

Comment: Thanks so much.you re the best ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to check if tags are overlapped, there's no direct way.

But in case  :

Do you just want to launch browser with specific screen size ?

make use of `ChromeOptions()`

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
```

In case if you would like to **maximize** the screen  :

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

Comment: Thanks.And also how to check if there is any interfered html elements visually ?

Comment: That still certainly is not possible at this point of time with selenium.